# broken pipe process using javaoctave

Tags: java, eclipse, octave

Hi I'm using the javaoctave package to bridge with octave from my computer to perform some calculation. However, I encountered the following error while compiling:

```
error: save: Unrecognized option '-'
Exception in thread "main" dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.reInstantiateException(OctaveExec.java:184)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.getFromFuture(OctaveExec.java:165)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.eval(OctaveExec.java:142)
    at dk.ange.octave.io.OctaveIO.get(OctaveIO.java:75)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.get(OctaveEngine.java:161)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.get(OctaveEngine.java:176)
    at learn.capability.CapabilityMeanVarianceEquation.learnCapabilities(CapabilityMeanVarianceEquation.java:214)
    at learn.graph.SimulatedAnnealingLearner.learnSynergyGraph(SimulatedAnnealingLearner.java:69)
    at parse.basketball.runner.GetPlayerFrequency.learnSynergyGraph(GetPlayerFrequency.java:112)
    at parse.basketball.runner.GetPlayerFrequency.main(GetPlayerFrequency.java:96)
Caused by: dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:65)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe to octave-process broken
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.read(OctaveExecuteReader.java:68)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.close(OctaveExecuteReader.java:96)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:61)
    ... 6 more
```

I'm not sure how I have come across this error. However, I have closely checked my input so I think there isn't any problem with that. The program I use have successfully run before.

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relates to a "bug" that exists in some Octave versions where the "-" option for the "save" command is not respected. This is probably fixed in later versions of Octave but until then you can modify JavaOctave like so:

In `DataReadFunctor.doReads(final Reader reader)`, comment the following lines out:

```
//        final String createByOctaveLine = readerReadLine(bufferedReader);
//        if (createByOctaveLine == null || !createByOctaveLine.startsWith("# Created by Octave")) {
//            throw new OctaveParseException("Not created by Octave?: '" + createByOctaveLine + "'");
//        }
```

In `OctaveIO.get(final String name)`, edit the following line:

```
final WriteFunctor writeFunctor = new ReaderWriteFunctor(new StringReader("save -text - " + name));
```

to this:

```
final WriteFunctor writeFunctor = new ReaderWriteFunctor(new StringReader("save -text /dev/stdout " + name));
```

These changes should work around the issue or at least set you in the right direction, but I wouldn't suggest this as a patch since the bug is actually in some versions of Octave (the documentation of 'save' does say that '-' is a valid option to output to terminal rather than to file)